# Accurate Mouse Picking on Skinned mesh (bones)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

We are using Skinned meshes (with bones to deform it), and are looking to implement face accurate mouse picking for the faces on the SkinnedMesh. ( so we can pick a face and get it's coordinates ) .

The mesh skin deformation is done on the GPU - which presents an issue reading transformed vertices back out - and for accurate mouse picking.

has anyone got any pointers to implement this functionality ? 
or is there a solution for this somewhere ( I have been looking for a while ) ?

We are using Three.js r67. - but happy to migrate to any version if there is a solution for this.

Thank you for your help / time.

Comment: See if http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html points you in the right direction -- as a start, at least.

Comment: That was a good starting point. As we needed accurate face detection - our picking routine - swapped materials for picking, assigned a unique colour to each face - and used that to identify which face was picked. Thank you.

Comment: I'm stuck on this issue. How can I render the same skinnedMesh in its current animation frame to two renderTargets with two different materials? Do I need to have two meshes and sync the animation? Can I clone the current state perfectly? I'm gonna do some test with the cloning, that seems like the easiest way.