# Raytracing animated object

Tags: three.js

Is in any way possible to get intersection of a ray and an animated skin?

I'm trying to highlight animated characters and other objects in my game on mouse over, rather accurately.

I've set up an example of this with my current approach, so you can see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Eskel/k44960Lp/1/

The model is rigged with a single bone and the bone animated to translate from side to side. Raytracing intersection turns it red. You can find the interaction in the middle, where I suppose it interacts with the static geometry.

I'm using Three.Raycaster

```
    raycaster.intersectObject mesh
```

Comment: [Duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285711/accurate-mouse-picking-on-skinned-mesh-bones). See if you can get some sort of [GPU picking](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html) to work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, somehow I missed it. Thanks for the link. Good to know I'm not the only one looking for a solution to this.